# Data ain't changed after submitted to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, submit

i have a code for updating data to myql. It looks doesn't have a problem but it ain't changed

my `update` code :

```
//previous data//
....
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
$nim = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, ($_POST['nim']));
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, ($_POST['name']));
$class1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, ($_POST['class2']));
$class2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, ($_POST['class1']));

if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/",$nim)) {
    $error = true;
    $nim_error = "NIM only contain numbers";
}
if (!preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z]/",$name)) {
    $error = true;
    $name_error = "NIM only contain numbers";
}
if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/",$class1)) {
    $error = true;
    $class1_error = "Class only contain numbers";
}
if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/",$class1)) {
    $error = true;
    $class2_error = "Class only contain numbers";
}

$result = "UPDATE users SET nim='$nim', name='$name', class1='$class1', class1='$class1' WHERE id='$id'";
mysqli_query($connection, $result);

}
?>
```

and this is my `html` code :

```
<div id="popup2" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <h2 class="range2">Edit</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="nim" placeholder="NIM" required/>
        <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <i>SK</i>
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="class1" placeholder="00" required/>
        <i>-</i>
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="class2" placeholder="00" required/>
        <input name="update" type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

is there any wrong code ? Thank you..

Comment: `$id` in `WHERE id='$id'` is not defined anywhere...

Comment: Apart from that: why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead of using the proper approach, the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding"?

Comment: @arkascha my primary is `$id` and in `register` part its unneeded to use `$id` i mean i'm not write that either , i just trying to make the code same with `register` part but its still ain't work

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand that last comment of yours. What I said is: since `$id` is undefined your resulting clause is `WHERE id=''` which (most likely) will not match any entry in your database. That probably is the reason why no data is changed, as you originally asked...

Comment: echo $result; and see the result sql string;

Comment: If you want a specific entry in your table to be changed, then you have to specify _which_ one. That is what the `id` is for. If you do not specify any in your query, how do you expect one to get changed?

Comment: @arkascha https://s12.postimg.org/3sbxenjy5/database.png this is my database

Comment: Ok, and so what? Did you understand what I wrote above?

Comment: @arkascha i just dont understand with `WHERE id='$id'` how do i know this is not defined anywhere ? look to the database, there is `id` :/

Comment: The _variable_ `$id` is not defined in your script! That has nothing to do with that _column_ `id` in your table.

Comment: @RaminDarvishov no result, nothing..

Comment: Add the `id` if the entry you are offering to be changed in a hidden input value to the html form. Then read it from `$_POST` just like all the other values you receive. That way you have a value for `$id` that can be inserted into your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @arkascha so i need to write variable above `$nim = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, ($_POST['nim']));` this ? with `$id = $_POST['id'];` ?

Comment: Yes, though obviously you also have to escape it, so `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, ($_POST['id']));`. _And_ you have to add the hidden input to your form.

Comment: @arkascha I've already tried that before but it said `Undefined index`

Comment: Good god, don't you read what I write? I wrote: "And you have to add the hidden input to your form. ". Which I already explained before that.

Comment: Answer me one question: "where do you think the `id` should come from when you want to run your `UPDATE` query?"? How should mysql know _which_ entry to update without an id?

Comment: @arkascha like this `<form method="post" type="hidden" name="id" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` ? i dont get it about this one haha

Comment: No, I said a hidden input element, not to give the form the name `id`. You know what a hidden input is? Like the other input elements you have _inside_ your form, only that the name is `id`, the value is the `id` of whatever entry you want to offer to be changed and the `type` attribute of that input element is set to "hidden": `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $idOfEntryToBeChanged; ?>">`

Comment: @arkascha could you "answer my question" not in comment section, so i can easily understand.

Comment: Sorry, to me this appeared trivial at first glance. I thought you only had a glitch in your code which is why I commented. Not it appears to be that, don't get that wrong, that you don't really know what yo are doing, or that I completely miss understood what you are trying to do. There is nothing I can post as an answer as far as I can see. Did you see my question I asked 4 comments above? You did not bother to answer it. May I ask why not? I wrote it for a purpose.

Comment: All of this looks like you did not yet understand how such things work. I suggest you google for a few "getting started" tutorials. It is not  the scope of StackOverflow to explain the absolut basics in extended form to each and every user asking the same questions over and over again. There are countless answers to things like this here on SO. _Learn from them_. This is a page to answer _specific_ questions with code and it is expected that the asking person knows the tools used and how things are working in general.

Comment: @Gilang Rizkie you must see Update query (echo $result)

Comment: @arkascha sorry, i didn't mean to offensive or trying to misunderstood your comment, i'm so grateful that you answering my question..

Comment: @arkascha i think i'm not really newb on this, i just need take a rest after writing the whole of my code for 24 hours :)

Comment: Ok, sure. I just said what my impression is. Since it read as if you don't really know how to reference an entry in your database. But certainly I may be totally wrong in that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**It is really hard to explain: Take a look.**

> If you want to update a single data you will need a identity(Primary
>   key). That mean which data you want to update.

**Below Example: check index.php file**

> 1. In file index.php change `dbname` to your database name in connection.
> 2. browse `project_url/index.php?id=1` [here use any id from your database]
> 3. Then update your data.

**index.php**

```
//Show existed data againist id
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id'=>$id));
    $data = $stmt->fetch();
    if (empty($data)) {
       echo "No data found in user table. Use proper ID.";
    }
}

//Update query
$msg = array();
if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']!='') { //operation is update, because id exist
    if($_POST['nim']!=0 && is_numeric($_POST['nim'])){
        $nim = $_POST['nim'];
    }else{
        $msg[]="Nim only can be number";
    }

    if($_POST['name']!=''){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }else{
        $msg[]="came only can not be empty";
    }

    if(is_numeric($_POST['class1'])){
        $class1 = $_POST['class1'];
    }else{
        $msg[]="Class1 only can be number";
    }

    if(is_numeric($_POST['class2'])){
        $class2 = $_POST['class2'];
    }else{
        $msg[]="Class1 only can be number";
    }
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if(count($msg)==0){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET nim=:nim, name=:name, class1=:class1, class2=:class2 WHERE id=:id');
        $result = $stmt->execute(array(
                    'nim'   => $nim,
                    'name'  => $name,
                    'class1'=> $class1,
                    'class2'=> $class2,
                    'id'    => $id,
                ));
        if($result){
            echo "successfully updated.";
        }else{
            echo "update failed";
        }
    }
}else{
    //You can run here insert operation because id not exist.
    echo "Id not set";
}
?>
<div id="popup2" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <h2 class="range2">Edit</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
        <?php foreach ($msg as $value) {
           echo $value."<br>";
        }?>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <?php if(isset($data)){?> 
                <input class="input" type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="nim" value="<?php echo isset($data)?$data['nim']:''?>" placeholder="NIM" required/>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo isset($data)?$data['name']:''?>" placeholder="Name" required/>
            <i>SK</i>
            <input class="input1" type="text" name="class1" value="<?php echo isset($data)?$data['class1']:''?>" placeholder="00" required/>
            <i>-</i>
            <input class="input1" type="text" name="class2" value="<?php echo isset($data)?$data['class2']:''?>" placeholder="00" required/>
            <input name="update" type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Credits for the effort to _try_ to explain all of this. Although such a "personal tutorial" certainly is not the idea behind SO. Only one thing: that code you now posted is wide open to sql injection attacks. Not sure if it is a good idea to post such an example...

Comment: `<input name="update">` should i keep this `update` or else ?

Comment: As your wish. @GilangRizkie. I have updated with `PDO` instead of `mysqli` to prevent sql injection. After checking previous code then check last updated code.

Answer (score 0):

My friend,
only do one thing to resolve this

echo $result = "UPDATE users SET nim='$nim', name='$name', class1='$class1', class1='$class1' WHERE id='$id'";

die;

then submit your form again and you will get your static query into your page then just copy that query and try to run into phpmyadmin then you will get your actual error.